# json Webservice that will pass Base64 code that will convert to image

Tags: json, web-services, jquery, base64

Specification:

- Server 2012
- Framework 3.5

I have already deployed my webservice in the server `http://ipaddress/eSignatureWS.asmx?op=SaveImg.`

**Problem**: when i change the ajax dataType to "json" or "text" it has an Internal Server Error, but when i used "script" it won't have an error but it don't save the image. When i try it locally it works using "json"/"text" but when i deployed it won't work anymore.

So here's my code:

**Jquery**

```
function signatureSave() {

var canvas = document.getElementById("newSignature"); // save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var signatureData = data.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");


var donum = "sampleImg"; //imagename
$.support.cors = true;
//var imgData = JSON.stringify(signatureData);

$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    async: false,
    url: "http://ipaddress/eSignatureWS.asmx?op=SaveImg",
    data: { "filename": donum, "imgBit": signatureData }, 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) { //alert(data);
        if (data.match("true")) {
            document.getElementById('errorImage').innerHTML = "Successfully Submitted!";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('errorImage').innerHTML = "Error occured.";
        }
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, testStatus, errorThrown) {
        document.getElementById('errorImage').innerHTML = errorThrown;
        alert(XMLHttpRequest + testStatus + errorThrown);
    }
})
```

**Webservice**

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string SaveImg(string filename, string imgBit)
    {
        try
        {

            string filepath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImgLocation"].ToString();
            string imgPath = filepath + filename + ".png";

            //creates a png image signature
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(imgPath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
                {
                    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imgBit);
                    bw.Write(data);
                    bw.Close();
                    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    string strJSON = js.Serialize("true");
                    return strJSON;
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check the edit section!**

I'm guessing you're not aware of the "maxJsonLength" attribute which is set to 100KB by default, in ASP.NET. I wasn't aware of that till the latest search I had to make about the same subject :)

In the Web.Config file you can change this default limitation to your needs.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="1000000"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

That one is 1.000.000 bytes which is ~1MB. You can set higher values if you need to send bigger files through your webservice.

Check that and please let me know if it works.

EDIT: I recently found out that this is not the only setting you should make. You should also set the "maxRequestLength" attribute of the httpruntime node in web.config file, like:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="10000" executionTimeout="10800" />
</system.web>
```

Here, maxRequestLength is in KBs, so 10000 means ~10MBs (9,77MB exactly). If users have low bandwidths and your requestlength requirement is bigger than 10MB, then you can set executionTimeout attribute to a higher value. That is in seconds, so 10800 means 3 hours.

I think you got the picture here.

Cheers!