# base64 images not call jquery success event

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

i have 1000 of images in sql server database in Binary format,i convert all images to Base64 PNG using c#

`byte[] imageSize = (byte[])reader["ImageSize"];
                    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageSize);`
when i try to get data through web services,it doest not return success.when i exclude images field from query code works, what is the fastest way to get base64 images using below code.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MapList.asmx/GetAllEmployees",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {

      // more ttask
    },
    error: function () {

        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

Comment: not acceptable way to do this !

Comment: i found the soution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325031/json-webservice-that-will-pass-base64-code-that-will-convert-to-image